# WalletConnect: Switching account doesn't change the signer?

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, wallet-connect

I use walletconnect/ethereum-provider@2.9.0 together with ethers@5.7.2.

The setup is very simple:

```js
const provider = await EthereumProvider.init({
  // params
});

const web3provider = new Web3Provider(provider);
```

I subscribe to events, call connect, etc. – everything works fine. I'm able to scan the qr-code and connect from the app (Metamask mobile).

But when I switch accounts in the app, while `accountsChanged` event gets fired with the new account, the call `web3provider.getSigner()` still returns the original account, with which I initially connected. Therefore, I can only send transactions from the original account no matter to which account I switch.

I'm wondering if it's by design? Should I disconnect and generate a new qr-code every time `accountsChanged` gets fired?